# Compiler picking the wrong overload

Tags: c#, asp.net, inheritance, polymorphism

Okay I have a derived class that has an overload to a method that's on my base class. I call what I think would match the method signature of the base class but instead my derived classes implementation is called. (The code below always prints out "MyDerived") Why is this?

```
    public class MyBase
    {
        public void DoSomething(int a)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("MyBase");
        }
    }

    public class MyDerived : MyBase
    {
        public void DoSomething(long a)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("MyDerived");
        }
    }


Main()
{
    MyDerived d = new MyDerived();
    d.DoSomething((int)5);
}
```

Comment: Sorry! I meant it prints out MyDerived! Typo I'm changing it now!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most people assume the DoSomething(int) overload on the base class is a better match than the DoSomething(long) overload.

**However**, since the variable is a derived type, that version of DoSomething will be called. The .NET runtime always favors the **most-derived compile-time type**.

If it finds a method signature that will work on the derived type it will use that before moving to any of the base class methods.
In general, you should **avoid overloading methods defined in base classes**.

Answer (score 5):

The behaviour you describe is correct. Many people consider it to be counterintuitive but it is carefully designed to prevent a brittle base class failure.

See my article on the subject for more details.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/future-breaking-changes-part-three